# Running out of memory.. How?

Tags: c, malloc

I'm attempting to write a solver for a particular puzzle. It tries to find a solution by trying every possible move one at a time until it finds a solution. The first version tried to solve it depth-first by continually trying moves until it failed, then backtracking, but this turned out to be too slow. I have rewritten it to be breadth-first using a queue structure, but I'm having problems with memory management.

Here are the relevant parts:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ...
    int solved = 0;
    do {
        solved = solver(queue);
    } while (!solved && !pblListIsEmpty(queue));
    ...
}

int solver(PblList *queue) {
    state_t *state = (state_t *) pblListPoll(queue);

    if (is_solution(state->pucks)) {
        print_solution(state);
        return 1;
    }

    state_t *state_cp;
    puck new_location;
    for (int p = 0; p < puck_count; p++) {
        for (dir i = NORTH; i <= WEST; i++) {
            if (!rules(state->pucks, p, i)) continue;
            new_location = in_dir(state->pucks, p, i);
            if (new_location.x != -1) {
                state_cp = (state_t *) malloc(sizeof(state_t));
                state_cp->move.from = state->pucks[p];
                state_cp->move.direction = i;
                state_cp->prev = state;
                state_cp->pucks = (puck *) malloc (puck_count * sizeof(puck));
                memcpy(state_cp->pucks, state->pucks, puck_count * sizeof(puck)); /*CRASH*/
                state_cp->pucks[p] = new_location;
                pblListPush(queue, state_cp);
            }
        }
    }

    free(state->pucks);

    return 0;
}
```

When I run it I get the error:

```
ice(90175) malloc: *** mmap(size=2097152) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Bus error
```

The error happens around iteration 93,000.
From what I can tell, the error message is from malloc failing, and the bus error is from the memcpy after it.

I have a hard time believing that I'm running out of memory, since each game state is only ~400 bytes. Yet that does seem to be what's happening, seeing as the activity monitor reports that it is using 3.99GB before it crashes. I'm using http://www.mission-base.com/peter/source/ for the queue structure (it's a linked list).

Clearly I'm doing something dumb. Any suggestions?

Comment: You are contradicting yourself three ways. 1. 400 bytes, 2. 3.99GB, 3. 93000*puck_count*sizeof(puck) allocations (that's a hell of a lot more than 400 bytes). What is the behavior you're actually observing? Are you forgetting to `free` the memory when you are done with it?

Comment: each game state is around 400 bytes, but it makes a lot of copies of it, apparently enough to fill 4 gigs of ram.
I'm not freeing all of the old memory (I free old puck-arrays but that's all), but that's because I need it to keep track of the moves taken so far.

Comment: @maxdj: Then how do you explain contradiction #3?

Comment: @Billy: I meant 93000 iterations of the outer loop. Each iteration of the outer loop produces multiple mallocs, depending on the number of valid moves in the game state.

Comment: You have 2 mallocs but only 1 free.

Comment: Okay, so then it's even more than `93000*sizeof(puck)*puck_count`. You need to free some of that at some point. Assuming `puck_count` is 5, and `puck` is 4 bytes wide (the minimum structure size emitted by most any compiler), that's almost 2GB right there, not counting the rest of your program's state. You need to free some stuff somewhere in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the result of `malloc`. If it's `NULL`, you might want to print out the length of that queue.

Also, the code snippet you posted didn't include any `free`s...

Comment: the result is NULL. The length of the queue is ~9 million (christ...)

Comment: @maxdj:  Well, 9m * 400 = ~3.6b, which is what you expected, right?

Comment: Well 400 bytes * 9e6 would close to run you out of memory. Do you ever remove items from the queue? It's possible that the breadth first algorithm actually uses more memory than you're able to give it. You may need to split the work into more pieces.

Comment: @James: yeah, I guess so. The problem is that I can't free previous states entirely, because I need to know which steps were taken to get to the solution.

Comment: @maxdj Then you either need to go back to depth-first search or use a pruned search tree of some sort. A* maybe.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `free()` the memory you've allocated manually after you're done with it; dynamic memory doesn't just "*free itself*"